# Screen recording of Windows "session 0"

Tags: windows-7, session, screen-recorder

Is there any possibility to record what is happening in [***session 0*** in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/426868/interactive-session-0-in-windows-7)? Can I accomplish this with some kind of software?

Comment: Which version of Windows?  Also, what exactly are you expecting to see/capture in Session 0?

Comment: Windows 7 Pro x64. I expect to record normal video (something like desktop capturing). I can run program in this session (so I can't see it normal in windows desktop, but I see it running in task manager). I can also switch from "normal" session to session 0 (if you do this, you see only black screen in background and nothing else) and normal program window running in foreground. It's hard to explain, and I can't even do screenshot...

Answer (score 5):

In Windows Vista+ there is no desktop in Session 0, and [it's isolated from the user on purpose](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation.aspx).

> The Microsoft Windows Vista operating system mitigates this security risk by isolating services in Session 0 and making Session 0 non-interactive.  In Windows Vista (and Windows Longhorn Server), only system processes and services run in Session 0.

Any service running in Session 0 that needs to interact with a user will have that facilitated via the [Interactive Services Detection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/04/27/what-is-interactive-services-detection-and-why-is-it-blinking-at-me.aspx) service, which will allow the console user to flip over and see what the service in Session 0 is trying to tell them:

[image]

But if/when they do flip over to "view the message", they won't be presented with anything other than the application needing interaction.

So (as far as I know) you can't "record" session 0 because you can't interact with it directly.

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear what you mean by "what is happening". "Process Monitor" is a program
available from Microsoft that can record numerous kinds of events about any user-mode
process, regardless of what "session" it's running in.

Comment: Like I mentioned in Techie007 comment, I want to record normal video (something like desktop capture). I see this as process normally in Task manager.